# how to modify the js for the :delete action in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-controls

I have a Post model which has title,body & author. I want to enable a feature where in whenever user tries to delete a post it should ask the authorname of the post and if the specified author name is same as `post.author` then he/she can delete a post else it shouldn't.

Please guide me through the steps I need to follow. I tried to create an `author_destroy` action but it fails in view it cannot find that action inside the Post index.

Note: I am using `author` field as supplant for `User` model.

Comment: how are you defining your routes? are you using only `resources :posts`?

Comment: `resources :posts do resources :comments end`

Comment: setting up the routes simply with `resources` wouldn't make that action available. Read more about [`routes` & `resources` here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend only showing the delete function to the author of the post, and hiding it for all other users, something in the erb like:

```
<% if @user == post.author %>
<%= link_to "delete", post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                            :title => "Delete #{post.title}" %>
<% endif %>
```

And then for the destroy action in the Posts controller:

```
def destroy
  Post.find(params[:id]).destroy if @user == post.author
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

Comment: I would still check (via authorization) whether the current user is allowed to call the `destroy` action on the server as it is possible to send a valid request to that method if you know the route and post id

Comment: made a simple example of a validation you could do as MWJ suggested

Comment: if I add this thing I get an error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end` in index. Is there any `end` missing here?

Comment: you shouldn't be missing one, but you can change the if statement on line two to a more traditional one to see if that's the issue, with `if @user == post.author` on one line, then `Post.find(params[:id]).destroy` on the next, followed by `end`, but that shouldn't be the issue...